# Vim picking up Cscope command instead of ctags?

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I have installed ctags but not installed cscope.

When I press Ctrl-], vim correctly takes me to the definition.
However, when I press Ctrl-t, it replies back with error - "E567: no cscope connections".

vim --version has +cscope in it.
I tried setting "set nocst" in my vimrc, but to no avail.

Comment: do you have  cscope_maps.vim installed? or any cscope related plugins/bundles?

Comment: Bravo! 
I have moved on to using Vundle for quite some time now and now, looking through  my .vim folder, I find the cscope_maps.vim. If you would post this as an answer, I would accept the solution.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Ok. But, I'm  glad we found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have `cscope_maps.vim` installed. Or, perhaps another related cscope related plugin/bundle. If so, you'll need to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
:set csto=1
```

From the documentation http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_cscop.html#csto

> The value of 'csto' determines the order in which |:cstag| performs a search.
>   If 'csto' is set to zero, cscope database(s) are searched first, followed
>   by tag file(s) if cscope did not return any matches.  If 'csto' is set to
>   one, tag file(s) are searched before cscope database(s).  The default is zero.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This did not solve my problem, because cscope.vim was setting the same option to 0 and apparently it gets called after the vimrc. (I didn't know I have it installed). 

Nonetheless, this will definitely help somebody in the same situation as I am and having different issues. Having that reference helped as well. Thanks a ton. 

(I have lost my privilege otherwise I would offer bonus points on this one too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have ctags installed and you are trying to use an outline viewer for your code, I would recommend using https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar. It works really well with just ctags.

If you are are using Vundle, install using

`Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'`

Comment: With due respect, how does this answer the question?

Comment: Apologies, I thought that you were looking to get an outline viewer for your code, which is why I recommended the tagbar plugin. I find it a lot better compared to vim's default tagsrch, which I assume is what you are trying to get working?

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks. That's very thoughtful of you.

I don't want outlines, when I am using some functions, I want to jump forward and backward to it to see if I am filling the options correctly, exactly what ctags does.